# extern in C programming

Tags: c, extern

I m using c18 compiler and i am declaring extern variable x in project.h

and in

```
project.h

  extern unsigned int x;
```

file1.c

```
 #include"project.h"

 foo1()
 {   
     x=200; 

 }
```

and in foo2.c

```
  #include"project.h"
foo2()
  {
     printf("%d",x);

  }
```

foo1 executes first ahead of foo2
I have made extern declaration in project.h 
and i defined x in foo1.c

should the foo2.c must have 200 as x value right.?

Comment: printf("x"); will print character 'x'

Comment: please show us `project.h`

Comment: shouldnt that be printf("%d",x)

Comment: so, what *do* you get as output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If those two files, plus a header containing only `extern int x;`, are all you have, it shouldn't even compile (well, it might compile but it won't link).

`extern int x;` lets the compiler know that `x` exists somewhere but *doesn't actually* bring it into existence.

The way this is normally done is to *define* the variable somewhere and *declare* it wherever it's used, something like:

```
project.h:
    extern int x;         // declare

file1.c:
    #include "project.h"  // declare in the header
    int main (void) {
        x = 200;
        printf ("x is %d\n", x);
        return 0;
    }

file2.c:
    #include "project.h"  // declare in the header
    int x;                // define it.
```

Comment: @pazdiablo.Thank you so much.so what must be done to make x=200 in file2 rather than defining again.

Comment: @Rookie, exactly what I have. Put an `int x;` somewhere outside all the functions in either your `file1.c` for `foo2.c`.

Comment: What will be the value of x in your file.c here.? Will it be zero now?

Comment: @Rookie, it will _start_ as `0`, being a static storage duration variable, but `main` will set it to `200` and that's the value it will retain until exit.

Comment: I had a strange feeling that in file2.c it will also have 200 as value.Sorry for all the troubles.:D.Its never been so clear as now.

Answer (score 0):

Use `printf("%d\n", x);` to print the variable instead of the character 'x'.

Comment: I am not sure, if OP explained his problem correctly... let wait for more info.